# How can I solve $\lim_{x \to \infty} (\cos \frac {1}{x})^{x^2}$ without differentiation/l'Hospital/Taylor Series?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> The given limit is:
>   $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left (\cos \dfrac {1}{x} \right)^{\displaystyle x^2} $$
>
> The answer is $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt e}.$

---

My working:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left (\cos \dfrac {1}{x} \right)^{\displaystyle x^2} $$
$$=\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\displaystyle \ln{\left(\cos \dfrac {1}{x} \right)^{\displaystyle x^2}}} $$
$$=\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\displaystyle \ln{\left( \sqrt {1-\sin^2 \dfrac {1}{x}} \right)^{\displaystyle x^2}}} $$
$$=\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\displaystyle \ln{\left({1-\sin^2 \dfrac {1}{x}} \right)^{\dfrac {x^2}{2}}}} $$

I am stuck at the 4th limit and I don't know how to go on. What should I do?

Comment: The answer to this limit is 1/((sqrt(e)).

Comment: Here is the page on [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). By the way, what's wrong with using differentiation or any of the more standard methods?

Comment: Can we solve this without differentiation notion ?

Comment: @Toby Mak So that's not possible?

Comment: What else are you planning on using then? I don't understand your [motivation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for asking this question.

Comment: (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2431795/limit-of-cos1-nn2-when-n-to-infty)   In here I see that most of the users didn't use differentiation,it's the same exercise but with different notation.

Answer (score 0):

I would write $$\left[\left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/x}\right)\right]^{x^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Do the substitution $x=1/t$, so the limit of the logarithm becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\log\cos t}{t^2}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\log(1-\sin^2t)}{t^2}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\log(1-\sin^2t)}{\sin^2t}\frac{\sin^2t}{t^2}
$$
Now you can use
$$
\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\log(1-u)}{u}=-1
$$